# How can I output a forward slash preceded by a back slash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a way to output a forward slash preceded by a back slash in ruby?

for example: `a\/b`

`"a\/b"` yields `a\b`

`"a\\/b"` yields `a\\/b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> puts 'a\/b'
a\/b
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> puts "a\\/b"
a\/b
=> nil
```

I get `a\/b` when I output `"a\\/b"`.  The single-quotes method should work as well, however.